# How to find technical documentation on hardware, as repair manuals, on the internet?

Tags: display, documentation

**formely:** I want to open (unscrew) my monitor, but I can't find instructions on the internet

I need to fix my monitor, but I couldn't find all the screws and the pressure points necessary to open it. Which are the English keywords that would help me to find such manuals and video tutorials?

BTW is a Samsung T220, I found 2 screws so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally find these instructions on the manufacturer's web site or not at all.

Samsung is not going to tell you haw to get into one of their CRT monitors for fear of a lawsuit after you kill or maim yourself (big capacitors can hold a lethal jolt for a *long* time), and the policy was probably simply extended to all their products.

---

BTW--many manufacturers hide some of the screws under rubber feet and bumpers or stickers. I guess because it makes the product look slick or for tamper evidence purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Many devices will have small arrows molded into the case that point to the screws you need to undo to open it.  Also check removable feet.   Some seams will have invisible latches you can see with strong lighting.