# Where do I find detailed technical drawings for Mac computers?

Tags: mac, macbook, drawing

Where do I find detailed technical drawings for Apple Mac computers?

I am specifically looking for details on the locations and sizes the following components on the MacBook and MacBook Pro for example:-

- USB Ports
- PowerPorts
- Firewire
- Keyboard
- etc

I am willing to pay for it if I can find an archive of them, however free would be preferred.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/20009/how-to-find-technical-documentation-on-hardware-as-repair-manuals-on-the-intern

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen technical drawing but they do provide outside dimensions in their techspec page. According to the [MacBook Technical Specifications Page](http://www.apple.com/macbook/specs.html) it is 1.08 inches (2.74 cm) high, 13.00 inches (33.03 cm) wide and a depth of 9.12 inches (23.17 cm).

Here are the links for the other MacBook Pro as

- [MacBook Pro 13"](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs-13inch.html) (0.95 inch (2.41 cm) **x** 12.78 inches (32.5 cm) **x** 8.94 inches (22.7 cm))
- [MacBook Pro 15"](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html) (0.95 inch (2.41 cm) **x** 14.35 inches (36.4 cm) **x** 9.82 inches (24.9 cm))
- [MacBook Pro 17"](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs-17inch.html) (0.98 inch (2.50 cm) **x** 15.47 inches (39.3 cm) **x** 10.51 inches (26.7 cm))

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the dimensions of the case, you should find this by nearly every resaler.

'Advanced' and more detailed technical drawings are most likely in a safe at the Apple HQ.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a technical drawing, but there are a lot of pictures of disassembled MacBook Pros (with instructions on removing various components) at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Browse/Mac).  Mayhap these will fill your need?